# Lerna + Ubuntu trying to start on ubuntu project withmonoperos

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, deployment, lerna

I'm trying to start project with following commands: 1) Lerna bootstrap 2) yarn run start.Bootstrap runs fine,I'm getting success message,but when I run yarn run start,in client folder and admin-next I get [image] I was trying to fix this by installing  @babel/runtime-corejs2 @babel-core @babel/preset-env babel-loader etc. tried to remove node_modules and reinstall whether all one by one or with Lerna bootstrap,but nothing resolved that issue.Is it problem somewhere in code or am I doing things in different way?

packages.json

```
{
  "name": "@project-m/app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build:server": "lerna run build --scope '@project-m/{core,adapters,db,mail,server}' --stream",
    "start:admin": "lerna run start --scope=@project-m/admin --stream",
    "start:server": "lerna run --parallel --no-sort start --scope=@project-m/server --scope=@project-m/core --scope=@project-m/db --scope=@project-m/adapters --scope=@project-m/mail",
    "start:client": "lerna run start --scope=@project-m/client --stream",
    "start": "lerna run --parallel start",
    "lint": "echo 'setup eslint later'"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^7.5.2",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^7.5.0",
    "@commitlint/config-lerna-scopes": "^7.5.1",
    "@types/node": "^11.13.8",
    "husky": "^2.1.0",
    "lerna": "^3.22.1",
    "lint-staged": "^8.1.5",
    "prettier": "^1.17.0",
    "tslint": "^5.16.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "tslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.js": "yarn lint",
    "**/*.ts": "tslint",
    "**/*.{css,json,md,yml}": "prettier -c",
    "**/.eslintrc": "prettier -c",
    "**/.babelrc": "prettier -c",
    "**/.prettierrc": "prettier -c"
  },
  "commitlint": {
    "extends": [
      "@commitlint/config-conventional",
      "@commitlint/config-lerna-scopes"
    ]
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS",
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "packages/*"
    ],
    "nohoist": [
      "**/babel**",
      "**/eslint**",
      "**/jest",
      "**/webpack**",
      "**/react**",
      "**/knex**",
      "**/customize-cra**",
      "**/**rsuite**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is there was an error with modules that hadn't been installed throughout process,couple modules from lodash and one module for tests